# Is there a way for using texture address mode advantages in Kepler read-only cache?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I have used textures many times for exploiting the address mode (mode border is the most I use)

Can the programmer express some kind of address mode using only read-only cache? (const __ restrict__ qualifiers) without having to use a texture.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, address mode is relevant only for texture objects. The address calculations that are done by special hardware units are only performed when working with the texture functions.